# Какая разница между array_map и array_walk?

Tags: php, массивы

Не могу понять какая разница между `array_map()` и `array_walk()`?

На php.net написано

> array_walk — Применяет заданную пользователем функцию к каждому
>   элементу массива. array_map — Применяет callback-функцию ко всем
>   элементам указанных массивов.

Вся разница только в том, что walk работает с одним массивом, а map может обрабатывать несколько? Тогда какой смысл от `array_walk()` ? Ведь можно использовать `array_map()`.

Comment: дальше то попробуйте почитать документацию? хотя бы типы возвращаемых значений функций.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Изменение значений:

  - `array_map` не может изменять значения внутри входных массивов, пока `array_walk` может; в частности, `array_map` никогда не меняет своих аргументов.
- Доступ к ключам доступа:

  - `array_map` не может работать с ключами массива, array_walkможет.
- Возвращаемое значение:

  - `array_map` возвращает новый массив, `array_walk` возвращает `true/false`.
    Следовательно, если вы не хотите создавать массив в результате
    прохождения одного массива, вы должны использовать его `array_walk`.
- Итерация нескольких массивов:

  - `array_map` также может принимать произвольное количество массивов, и он
    может перебирать их параллельно, а `array_walk` работает только на
    одном.
- Передача произвольных данных в обратный вызов:

  - `array_walk` может получить дополнительный произвольный параметр для
    передачи обратного вызова. Это в основном не имеет значения с PHP 5.3
    (когда были введены анонимные функции ).
- Длина возвращаемого массива:

  - Результирующий массив `array_map` имеет ту же длину, что и наибольший
    входной массив; `array_walk` не возвращает массив, но в то же время он
    не может изменить количество элементов исходного массива;
    `array_filter` выбирает только подмножество элементов массива в
    соответствии с функцией фильтрации. Он сохраняет ключи.

Пример:

```
<pre>
<?php

$origarray1 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);
$origarray2 = array(2.4, 2.6, 3.5);

print_r(array_map('floor', $origarray1)); // $origarray1 stays the same

// changes $origarray2
array_walk($origarray2, function (&$v, $k) { $v = floor($v); }); 
print_r($origarray2);

// this is a more proper use of array_walk
array_walk($origarray1, function ($v, $k) { echo "$k => $v", "\n"; });

// array_map accepts several arrays
print_r(
    array_map(function ($a, $b) { return $a * $b; }, $origarray1, $origarray2)
);

// select only elements that are > 2.5
print_r(
    array_filter($origarray1, function ($a) { return $a > 2.5; })
);

?>
</pre>
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
0 => 2.4
1 => 2.6
2 => 3.5
Array
(
    [0] => 4.8
    [1] => 5.2
    [2] => 10.5
)
Array
(
    [1] => 2.6
    [2] => 3.5
)
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3432257/difference-between-array-map-array-walk-and-array-filter)